# Is there any way in botium using which I can assert the response text with emojis?

Tags: automation, chatbot

I have response from bot like " Hi there! ". does botium provide any support to test emojis in response text

Answer (score 0):

[BotiumScript](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/491664/Botium+Scripting+-+BotiumScript) files are UTF-8, so as long as you are using UTF-8 characters it will work.